# Why is there no "save over" popup?

Tags: interface, blend-files, file-browser, saving

I know that, the file name turns red when the file name is the same as an existing filename in the "save as" window. But that is not enough. It has happened to me repeatedly that I overwrote a file by accidentally double clicking on an existing file. Or I edit the name of the file and there is another old file with the same name. Then by hitting enter twice it is already being overwritten and there is no way I can stop it. Hitting escape doesn't work even if it is taking a while to save it.
Also hitting ctrl+S by accident sometimes overwrites earlier versions that I might want to go back to.

I did some research and apparently there used to be a popup that people couldn't get rid of but now it is completely gone.(I am using Blender 2.93.2)

Is there any way to bring that warning back?

Comment: In terms of data loss this is just one of many ways you can lose work.  In the interest of protecting yourself completely and not just solving this one issue I recommend a continuous backup with file version history.  Google drive set to sync your project folder will suffice.  If you already have this, go look at the file on the web and you can download previous versions.

Comment: Thank you for that interesting tip.
But I would still like to know how to solve this specific issue.